# Probability on sequence space

Tags: probability, probability-theory

A question asks about a "random experiment" where a fair coin is tossed independently countably infinitely many times, and then asks about some "probabilities". It's not clear to me the meaning of this. The sample space would be $2^\mathbb{N}$. But i don't see a natural sigma-algebra to endow this space with, let alone a probability. Is this question even rigorous enough?

Comment: It is thinking about this which leads to the concept of "tail events" and [Kolmogorov's zero–one law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_zero%E2%80%93one_law)

Comment: You should look at Kolomogorov's Exisitence Theorem (a.k.a. Kolomogorov's Consistency Theorem).

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy which Wikipedia calls the [Kolmogorov Extension Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_extension_theorem)

Comment: The question is not rigorous enough if you are dealing with measure-theoretic definitions, because you would want verification that the events whose probability you wish to find are actually measurable. In short, in this case the question must either provide you with a sigma-algebra, or you'll have to come up with one yourself. The logical idea is to think of a probability measure that would allow each component to behave like an independent coin toss. That's what the Kolmogorov extension theorem is about : putting all those coin tosses together but keeping things rigorous.